Why are trait objects usually used via references (&dyn Trait) or smart Pointers (like Box<dyn Trait>)?
In Rust, why are trait objects usually used via references (&dyn Trait) or smart Pointers (like Box<dyn Trait>)? Does it have to be? Or is it better to use it this way?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html

"Best practices" is not suitable for a Stack Overflow question, and anyway you can ask one question per post.

@ChayimFriedman ok，I've deleted that sentence.

@Masklinn Thanks, it can answer some of my doubts.

Did you try to actually make a trait object without some kind of pointer? If not, try.

Unfortunately this question is still not suitable for SO after the edit. You should try to find a concrete problem which is representative of this issue. That is, a specific program, which either does not compile, or produces an incorrect result, or is otherwise clunky and un-ergonomic. Include the actual program and the attempts you've made to try to improve that program.

Contrary to what @user2407038 said, I believe this question might have its place (iff it was not asked already), if you will clarify more what you mean. Are you asking "is there some way to use dyn Trait without smart pointers" or "can we do what we do with smart pointers (i.e. refer to values as dyn Trait) without smart pointers"?

@user2407038 This question clearly does not ask about a specific program that does not compile to OP. This is clearly a question asked to know more about trait objects, not to solve some bug in some code. And such questions are also valid here, assuming they are asked correctly.

As a side note: if you didn't put the closing > because it will make SO think it is a HTML tag, beware that you can (and should) put it inside a code mark.

I've voted to reopen because I think this is perfectly answerable as is. "Why are trait objects usually used [these ways]" has a definite answer and the question doesn't need an underlying goal (like avoiding smart pointers).

Ok. As hard as I tried, I couldn't find a proper explanation of DSTs on site. So it seems @kmdreko is right and we need to reopen this.

They are handled via references and smart pointers because they won't compile otherwise:
trait Foo {}
struct Bar;
impl Foo for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let f1: dyn Foo = Bar;
    let f2: dyn Foo = Bar as dyn Foo;
}

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:23
  |
6 |     let f1: dyn Foo = Bar;
  |             -------   ^^^ expected `dyn Foo`, found `Bar`
  |             |
  |             expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected trait object `dyn Foo`
                   found struct `Bar`
  = help: `Bar` implements `Foo` so you could box the found value and coerce it to the trait object `Box<dyn Foo>`, you will have to change the expected type as well

error[E0620]: cast to unsized type: `Bar` as `dyn Foo`
 --> src/main.rs:7:23
  |
7 |     let f2: dyn Foo = Bar as dyn Foo;
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
help: consider using a box or reference as appropriate
 --> src/main.rs:7:23
  |
7 |     let f2: dyn Foo = Bar as dyn Foo;
  |                       ^^^

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn Foo` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |     let f1: dyn Foo = Bar;
  |         ^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Foo`
  = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
  = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature
help: consider borrowing here
  |
6 |     let f1: &dyn Foo = Bar;
  |             +

A dyn Trait is a dynamic type that represents any potential concrete type that implements that Trait. Since it is representing a variety of types of potentially different sizes, it itself does not have a fixed size. This is called a dynamically sized type (DST).
Because they don't have a fixed size, there are limits to where we can put them. In particular a DST cannot be stored in a variable; and if stored in a struct, it makes that struct a DST which therefore also cannot be stored in a variable. There is a unsized locals RFC that may make it possible in the future, but right now its fate is unclear.
Side note: you can still reference a variable as a dynamic trait but that is because the variable is still a known concrete type even though the trait object accesses it dynamically:
fn main() {
    let b = Bar;
    let f: &dyn Foo = &b;
}

So in order to work with a DST, it requires some indirection; the value must be stored elsewhere and only referred to through a reference or smart pointer like Box (Rc, Arc, also work).

Technically tangential but worth mentioning anyway: references and smart pointers to trait objects are "fat". This means they actually store two pointers: one to the data and another to a v-table that maps to the trait functions associated with that trait implementation. See What is a "fat pointer"? for more info.
